# Every time I try to access the CashRegister.purchaseItem method it says that cannot read property

Tags: javascript

Create a script called retail_store.js. In this script code the following:
A. Class and Constructor Creation (25 Points)
 RetailItem Class
 Create a constructor function or ES6 class for a RetailItem object. The RetailItem
object should store the following data in attributes: item description, units in inventory,
and price.
 CashRegister Class (25 points)
 Create a constructor function or ES6 class for a CashRegister object that will be
used with the RetailItem class. The CashRegister object should be able to internally
keep an array of RetailItem objects.
B. Methods to add (25 Points)
 CashRegister Class

The class should have the following methods:
o A method named purchaseItem that accepts a RetailItem object as an
argument. Each time the purchaseItem method is called, the RetailItem
object that is passed as an argument should be added to the list of
retailItems the CashRegister contains.
o A method named getTotal that returns the total price of all the RetailItem
objects stored in the CashRegister objects internal list.
o A method named showItems that writes the information about each retail
item stored in the cash register to the console.
o A method named clear that should clear CashRegister object’s internal
list.

Comment: What code are you executing to get the "cannot read property" message?

Comment: Please provide a code example for us to follow along with.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot read your mind, add some code so we know what you need help with.